# Command \counterwithout already defined

Tags: mactex

I just loaded my default college template and tried to LaTeX to see the results. It works normally on a linux machine, but crashes on a MacBook with this error:

[image]

This is the only time counterwithout is referenced in the following format:

> \counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
>
> \counterwithout{table}{chapter}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your system up-to-date? chngcntr is no longer needed with a current latex.

Comment: don't paste an image but the actual textual log

Comment: the 1.1 version of `chngcntr` (more precisely `2018/04/09 v1.1a`) automatically aborts its input. So there is something broken or not updated in your system. Line 42 of current `chngcntr` is a comment line so you must be using some earlier version. In current version `\newcommand{\counterwithout}{\@ifstar{\c@t@soutstar}{\c@t@sout}}` is on line 53.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 2):

As Ulrike has said the functionality of my `chngcntr` package has been incorporated, much to my surprise and delight, into basic LaTeX.

In order to prevent this type of problem in the future I suggest that somebody (not me) modifies the `chngcntr` package code so that if it is used with the current LaTeX base then a warning is given and the package is not loaded.

Comment: But this is already the case... `:)` `% version 1.1 this package has been adoped into the format so does not  % need to do anything in current latex releases.`